# Implementing feature to show human-readable activity history to user

Tags: design, architecture

I'm creating a web app and looking to have a feature to show a history of updates/activities of other users to the current user. For example if another user creates a project. The user should see something like:

"User A created Project 1 - Date, Time"

Another example of such feature in Postman:

[image]

How can I implement this feature?

I have made the following attempts but none seem to be covering potential issues:

My first thought was to create a history table in my db with `user id, date` and a human readable `text` which I will add items to from my API when users are interacting with the API through web app. The issue of course is that it's not holding references to the objects that are edited, created etc. Then I thought of adding references (eg: `projectId`) but since these activities can vary a lot (changes, edits etc to various components) and this means I have to add a lot of columns. Third approach was to have that history table having these columns:

```
userId, date, activityType, objectRef, objectType
```

And then convert this to a human readable text at runtime. That looks like the best approach but then we could have scenarios where an object is deleted and that `objectRef` will become invalid.

Another issue is that we may want to have multiple objects in one history item. For example: "User A edited File 1 in Project 1".

Comment: First analyze what precisely you want, otherwise this cannot be answered. Do you want the names to reflect the state at the time of making the log entry, or at the time of reading the log entry? Do you want to make sure that if the route changes in the future, that your old log messages will be using the new route? What happens when a linked resource is deleted, how does the log message handle that? What if you update the particular message template, do you want the old log messages to use the new version? ... This is not clear from your answer and can completely change your approach.

Answer (score 6):

Understand that this is a log. It’s a log whose audience is the user. But it’s still a log.

That means it doesn’t point at things that might ever be deleted. If it points at anything, it points at stale immutable copies of what was way back when. Show history with history.

You can have clickable links to the live versions of things. But don’t confuse the user about which is which. History is history. Live is live.

As for human readable, that’s presentation. Just because you timestamp in Unix time doesn’t mean you can’t show it as: “5 minutes ago”. Just never put that string in the database or a log file. Generate that human readable string with logic. It’s basic presentation-model separation.

Conform to these rules and it should avoid most of the problems.

But if you have a use case that just can’t conform to these rules consider not using this to meet that need. Do that somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve so much accuracy in your "logs", you need fine-grained control over your data model and the actions applicable to it. Fine-grained enough for you to be able to track:

- the precise action involved (commands or requests)
- the precise changes (elements & attributes involved; old values & new values)
- the point in time (moment) the action took place
- the user(s) involved

If displaying changes only (elements' names, attributes and values) is not enough and you want to show the entire state of the data before/after the action, then you need either to recreate the history (re-executing actions up to a concrete point in time) or persist the state of the data twice, before and after the change. For simplicity, let's call these copies: snapshots.

If one action involves changes in two or more elements of the model, then you have to make a snapshot of each element. To correlate actions with snapshots, you can rely on time ranges or add a correlation ID (transaction ID) to actions and snapshots.

Note that, this is not as simple as creating a new table with X or X+1 columns. It's a lot more complicated. The kind of change log you want is a consequence of an architecture which favours it (at low cost and effort).

As for the readability (UX), as @candied_orange says, it's a matter of data presentation. Log entries can be coded as templates, the historical data you have fills the gap.

```json
${user} ${action.name} the ${target.type} : ${target.name} | ${parent.type} : ${parent.name} | ${child.type} : ${child.name}
```

Each reference to an element points to that element at a point in time.

```json
<a href="/${target.type}/${target.ID}/snapshots/${action.timestamp}">${target.name}</a>.
```